# preserving diagonality of a tensor

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Under what conditions does a diagonal tensor remain diagonal after a coordinate rotation C. If $ A_{11}=A_{22}=A_{33}$. what has to be true about C for A' to be diagonal

Comment: If $A$ is a diagonal matrix with $A_{11} = A_{22} = A_{33}$ then $A = \alpha I$, i.e. $UAU^{-1} = A$.

Comment: What would happen if the diagonal components were not equal, can A still be diagonal after a coordinate rotation